# c# Access of row after DataSet copy operation throws an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a DataSet containing several strongly typed datatables. I use copy operation to copy both schema and data to a new DataSet as follows:

```
DataSet dsNew = dsOld.Copy();

EmployeeDataTable dtEmpl = (EmployeeDataTable) dsNew.Tables["Employee"];
string sColName = dtEmpl.Columns[0].ColumnName; // this line correctly assigns 'EmployeeId' to sColName

EmployeeRow row = dtEmpl[0];
int id = row.EmployeeId;
```

The last line throws an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'!

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: Column 'EmployeeId' does not belong to table Employee". Using DataSet Visualizer on dtEmpl all of the table data is displayed correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the column by name instead.

Like this:

```
int id = (int)row["EmployeeId"];`
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you have the right columns in the table by looking at the `dtEmpl.Columns` collection.

The reason for your problem may be that you are copying the data set and working on the copy instead of the original. If that is the case, then accessing the columns using the indexer instead of the property may work.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing: making a copy of a dataset and then work on the copy. I you cannot do that, then what's the point in making a copy of the dataset in the first place?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have run into the same issue as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756746/table-property-broken-after-c-sharp-typed-dataset-copy

Comment: It is a similar issue. The thread you mention refers to a strongly typed dataset and the attempt to access its datatables via the named table link. My post refers to strongly typed datatables and the attempt to access table fields using properties.

Comment: Rune, if I try to access the column via the index operator it works. Still, the question remains why copy operation breaks all datatable properties.

Comment: If you look at the Copy method of the DataSet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.copy.aspx) you will see that it returns a DataSet and not a typed dataset. So you could try to cast the return value of the Copy method and see if that works.

Comment: My DataSet is not typed. Instead, the datatables inside it are strongly typed. If I try to cast on the type of the datatables the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

To access you objet in an exception treatment, write your code this way:

```
DataSet dsNew = dsOld.Copy();
try
{
... your code ...
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
 ... here you can access dsNew ...
}
```

Comment: I am not asking how I can handle the exception thrown. I just do not understand why the exception is thrown in the first place. Using DataSet Visualizer on dtEmpl all of the table data is displayed
correctly.